# Setting execution time limit for each cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: configuration, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project for customizing Jupyter notebook. I want to add a feature for **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** so that it will automatically interrupt a cell after this time limit 
Example: 
I have set MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 5sec.
I run an infinite while loop, so It will automatically terminate this while loop after 5 sec.

Question:
How can I add such **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** in Jupyter Notebook's settings so that I can able to interrupt cell execution after this time limit?

Comment: What is your question?!

Comment: How can I add such MAX_EXECUTION_TIME feature so that I can able to interrupt cell execution after this time limit?

Comment: Did you get an answer yet?